# Loop loading when trying to slect tenant when adding Azure AD Service Dependency - VS 2022

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've created a NET 6 web app to study how works the Azure AD B2C.
So after doing all the configurations under Azure Portal, I went to Visual Studio 2022 to set the Service Dependency
[Service selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eiwX.png)

But when I select the "Microsoft Identity Platform" no option for "Tenants" is show, a infinite loop of loading is presented on the screen.
[Loading loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwVRs.png)

Thanks.